# Codeigniter Cannot Remove index.php after move to virtual host

Tags: codeigniter

I created the virtual in wamp server. Everything is working but i can't able to remove the index.php. I don't know how to write the .htaccess.

Here is the details

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot E:/Projects/OnGoing/bonanza/dev.bonanza.com
ServerName dev.bonanza.com
    <Directory "E:/Projects/OnGoing/bonanza/dev.bonanza.com">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride None
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my htaccess

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
# - index.php (DO NOT FORGET THIS!)
# - robots.txt
# - favicon.ico
# - Any file inside of the media/ directory
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|media|uploads|js|css|images|plugins|source|files|fonts|lib|plugins) - [PT,L]

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you setup your host file correctly to read the path of your site? For me  I used this all the time works fine in development server.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, check this - 127.0.0.1 dev.bonanza.com
this is what i added in the host

Comment: did you check my virtual host settings? anything wrong in that? actually everything is works for me but can't remove the index.php from the url :(

Comment: try changing DocumentRoot "E:/Projects/OnGoing/bonanza/dev.bonanza.com" ,if still not working can you share the folder structure.

Comment: Change also  AllowOverride None to   AllowOverride All

Comment: hey AllowOverride All works, thank you so much, You are really great